# Check if nullable int has value and compare value to another integer

Tags: c#

Question might be more appropriate in StackOverflow, however I'd also like a review.

I'd like to make my code inline as I feel like this could be possible, I'm just not sure how.

```
int highestWeightOfParcel  = 0;
if (collo.WeightGrammes.HasValue)
{
    if (collo.WeightGrammes > highestWeightOfParcel)
    {
        highestWeightOfParcel = collo.WeightGrammes.Value;
    }
}
```

Could I apply the same technique as this? :

```
int heigth = collo.HeightMm.HasValue ? collo.HeightMm.Value < 10 ? 1 : (collo.HeightMm.Value / 10) : 0,
```

Is there a 'better'/simpler way of writing this?

Comment: This question severely lacks context. The code also does not make any sense because when `highestWeightOfParcel  = 0` then it's the same as writing `highestWeightOfParcel  = collo.WeightGrammes ?? 0`. This meas if it's not-null then it'll always be the highest value. Both `if`s are completely unnecessary. I bet this is a part or a loop...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is really no need to check `HasValue` in this situation. It is sufficient to compare with `highestWeightOfParcel` because if `collo.WeightGrammes` is `null` the comparison is false for any value of `highestWeightOfParcel`:

```
int highestWeightOfParcel  = 0;

if (collo.WeightGrammes > highestWeightOfParcel)
{
    highestWeightOfParcel = collo.WeightGrammes.Value;
}
```

Comment: @Paramone `Nullable<T>` will NEVER throw `NullReferenceException` if you access its `Value` property when it has not a value. If this happen then to be `null` is `collo` (assuming it's a reference type) and for that you have `?.`. That said THIS is the _right_ code, compiler does everything correctly (not a surprise). If you REALLY want a single line then your first snippet MIGHT be rewritten as `highestWeightOfParcel  = Math.Max(highestWeightOfParcel, collo.WeightGrammes ?? 0)` (assuming `highestWeightOfParcel` cannot be negative).

Comment: Same comment as under the accepted answer: this code assigns twice to the same variable. That’s code smell and, although it might be seen as justified in this code, it’s really unnecessary. Treat all variables as readonly, this dramatically simplifies code flow.

Comment: @konrad it's a reasonable guess to assume that `=0` is fictional otherwise the whole code is a smell. Single assignment is a golden rule (especially if you do not _force_ it chaining complex expressions and multiple ternary operators like in the other OP's example). It has however, other disadvantages (often it's about readability and quick review of test coverage). Of course to introduce a function is even better.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Exactly. Just encapsulate complex assignment expressions. But the one in this answer isn't complex enough to warrant this. This should be one expression, one line of code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'd agree, unfortunately this question is too much _fictional_ to suggest something useful (Is `Math.Max()` enough? Is `highestWeightOfParcel` truly initialized with 0? Is it part of a more complex context which is (or should be) already in a separate function?)

Answer (score 1):

```
int highestWeightOfParcel  = (collo.WeightGrammes.HasValue && (collo.WeightGrammes > highestWeightOfParcel))? collo.WeightGrammes.Value:0;
```

That line code can perhaps be written as above. However, ternary operator tends to become unreadable fairly quickly. Alternate option could be this:

```
int highestWeightOfParcel  = 0;
if ((collo.WeightGrammes.HasValue) && 
    (collo.WeightGrammes > highestWeightOfParcel)) {
        highestWeightOfParcel = collo.WeightGrammes.Value;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I have to agree with you, though. It does get somewhat unreadable as it goes on and on..

Comment: I disagree with your assessment of the conditional operator. Your proposed code is worse, for a number of reasons — but foremost because you’re assigning to `highestWeightOfParcel` *twice*, which I would immediately flag as code smell in a code review. Even though C# doesn’t generally support this, it simplifies code tremendously if you consider every variable as readonly. That’s why things like `?.` and `??` were added to the language.

Comment: @KonradRudolph erm..you need to declare `highestWeightOfParcel` ahead of if block. to use it outside the if block. Null conditional operator (?./?[]) are to eliminate null checks and keep code thread safe. While null coalesce operator again is to be used in case of null checks. The `if` statement in sample code it not limited to null check only and thus disqualify these operators. As for ternary operator being unreadable, that is purely subjective so to each one his own.

Comment: @danish You don't need to declare it beforehand, since you don't need to use it inside the conditional. In fact this comparison makes absolutely no sense here. Compare to the literal value. And use `Math.Max` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of C# you are using...

```
collo?.WeightGrammes > 0 ? collo.WeightGrammes.Value : 0
```

`?.` is null propagation. If 'collo' is null, then 'collo?.X' is also null. 
`null` is not `>0`

If you are working your way through a list of values... then you can use linq

```
List<Collo> list= new List<Collo> (){... some values ... };
var max = list.Max ( ( c ) => c?.WeightGrammes ) ?? 0;
```

Comment: `collo.WeightGrammes` is of type `int?`. The first if is to check whether the property is `null`, not `collo` as a whole. `collo?.WeigthGrammes` could be replaced with `collo.WeightGrammes ?? 0` though.